# Batch reverse geocoding

Tags: gis, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Recently I found myself in need to perform large batch reverse-geocoding operations.
Large means something about 20k points per request.
I was looking at [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) as standalone server. But there is no clue in docs about batch requests (or I just couldn't find it).

Thus the questions is:
1: Could I perform something like this with Nominatim
2: If not - is there other standalone solutions [Not service. May be proprietary]. Main zone of interest is Europe, if it's relevant.
3: What will be approximate time consumption of such request.

Or I am facing building own geocoder above pgsql + postGIS?

thx in advance.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: It seems i'v worked something out with Nominatim... but i couldn't remember specifics. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a current question, but in the absence of any answers.. There seem to be 2 main solutions. You can either:

1. use the Google geocoding API, but this will limit you to a check every few seconds, which will make large bulk geocoding very slow, or
2. download a comprehensive database of place names (such as http://www.geonames.org/), and use a GIS to calculate the nearest points to your data at whatever hierarchical level is most appropriate.